# Adding legend to a GIF in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, legend, time-series, animation

How can I add the legend created to the GIF image?
I have this code where I created a GIF with the ui.Thumbnail() function from an image collection and I have already added the years corresponding to each image composing the animation. But I don't know how to add the legend I created with the ui.panel function.

Can you help me with this code?

```
var myRegion =  ee.FeatureCollection("users/marianaguerralar/caldensl_poly")

var asset2_1 = ee.Image('projects/MapBiomas_Pampa/public/collection2/mapbiomas_pampa_collection2_integration_v1')
var image2 = asset2_1.where(asset2_1.eq(3).or(asset2_1.eq(4)).or(asset2_1.eq(12)), 2).clip(myRegion);

print(image2)

  
var geometry=myRegion.geometry().bounds()
  
var colors = ["#ffffff", "#1f4423", "#006400", "#32cd32", "#00ff00", "#ffffff", "#76a5af", "#ffffff", "#935132", "#935132", "#45c2a5", "#b8af4f", "#b8af4f", "#ffffff", "#ffd966", "#ffd966", "#ffffff", "#e974ed", "#ffffff", "#d5a6bd", "#ffefc3", "#ea9999", "#d0d0d0", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#0000ff", "#d5d5e5", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#ffffff", "#0000ff"]


var IC=ee.ImageCollection([

  
  image2.select("classification_1985").set({'year': "1985"}),
  image2.select("classification_1986").set({'year': "1986"}),
  image2.select("classification_1987").set({'year': "1987"}),
  image2.select("classification_1988").set({'year': "1988"}),
  image2.select("classification_1989").set({'year': "1989"}),
  image2.select("classification_1990").set({'year': "1990"}),
  image2.select("classification_1991").set({'year': "1991"}),
  image2.select("classification_1992").set({'year': "1992"}),
  image2.select("classification_1993").set({'year': "1993"}),
  image2.select("classification_1994").set({'year': "1994"}),
  image2.select("classification_1995").set({'year': "1995"}),
  image2.select("classification_1996").set({'year': "1996"}),
  image2.select("classification_1997").set({'year': "1997"}),
  image2.select("classification_1998").set({'year': "1998"}),
  image2.select("classification_1999").set({'year': "1999"}),
  
  
  image2.select("classification_2000").set({'year': "2000"}),
  image2.select("classification_2001").set({'year': "2001"}),
  image2.select("classification_2002").set({'year': "2002"}),
  image2.select("classification_2003").set({'year': "2003"}),
  image2.select("classification_2004").set({'year': "2004"}),
  image2.select("classification_2005").set({'year': "2005"}),
  image2.select("classification_2006").set({'year': "2006"}),
  image2.select("classification_2007").set({'year': "2007"}),
  image2.select("classification_2008").set({'year': "2008"}),
  image2.select("classification_2009").set({'year': "2009"}),
  image2.select("classification_2010").set({'year': "2010"}),
  image2.select("classification_2011").set({'year': "2011"}),
  image2.select("classification_2012").set({'year': "2012"}),
  image2.select("classification_2013").set({'year': "2013"}),
  image2.select("classification_2014").set({'year': "2014"}),
  image2.select("classification_2015").set({'year': "2015"}),
  image2.select("classification_2016").set({'year': "2016"}),
  image2.select("classification_2017").set({'year': "2017"}),
  image2.select("classification_2018").set({'year': "2018"}),
  image2.select("classification_2019").set({'year': "2019"}),
  image2.select("classification_2020").set({'year': "2020"}),
  image2.select("classification_2021").set({'year': "2021"})
  
  ])

var palette = ['#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61','#fee08b',
  '#ffffbf','#d9ef8b','#a6d96a','#66bd63','#1a9850'];
var vis2 = {min:1, max: 33,  palette: colors}

 
print(IC)


var tempCol = IC

// Define arguments for animation function parameters.
var videoArgs = {
  dimensions: 768,
  region: myRegion.geometry().bounds(),
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  crs: 'EPSG:3857',
};

var text = require('users/gena/packages:text'); // Import gena's package which allows text overlay on image

var visualizeImage = function(image) {
  return image.visualize(vis2).clip(tempCol.geometry().bounds()).selfMask()
}



var annotations = [
  {position: 'right', offset: '1%', margin: '35%', property: 'label', scale: Map.getScale() * 0.10}
]



function addText(image){
  
  var year = ee.Number(image.get('year')); // get the time stamp of each frame. This can be any string. Date, Years, Hours, etc.
  //print(year)
var year = ee.String('Year: ').cat(ee.String(year))//convert time stamp to string 
 var image = image.visualize({ //convert each frame to RGB image explicitly since it is a 1 band image
      forceRgbOutput: true,
      min: 1,
      max: 33,
      palette: colors
    }).set({'label':year}); // set a property called label for each image
  
  var annotated = text.annotateImage(image, {}, geometry, annotations); // create a new image with the label overlayed using gena's package
  
  return annotated 
  
}

var tempCol = tempCol.map(addText) //add time stamp to all images

print(ui.Thumbnail(tempCol, videoArgs)); //print gif


Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: tempCol,
  description: 'video_mapa',
  dimensions: 768,
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  region: myRegion.geometry().bounds(),
});


//Crear leyenda para visualizar en el GIF


//video youtube 

var panel = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '5px;'
  }
})

var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Tipos de coberturas',
  style: {
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    margin: '0px;'
  }
})

panel.add(title)

var color = ['309e48',"#ffefc3","#45c2a5","#ea9999", "#0000ff"]
var lc_class = ['Vegetacion Natural', 'Agricultura-pastura', 'Area húmeda natural', 'Area no vegetada', 'Cuerpos de agua']

var list_legend = function(color, description) {
  
  var c = ui.Label({
    style: {
      backgroundColor: color,
      padding: '10px',
      margin: '4px'
    }
  })
  
  var ds = ui.Label({
    value: description,
    style: {
      margin: '5px'
    }
  })
  
  return ui.Panel({
    widgets: [c, ds],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
  })
}

for(var a = 0; a < 5; a++){
  panel.add(list_legend(color[a], lc_class[a]))
}

Map.add(panel)
Map.addLayer(image2.select("classification_2021"), vis2, "2021" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the [text](https://github.com/gee-community/ee-packages-js/blob/main/src/text) module from `users/gena/packages:text`, which as you can see works ok to display some small text. However, it renders the text by modifying the image itself, e.g. :

[image]

so the quality of the text is evidently not that great. Now you want to add some legends with significantly more text.. while it could be technically possible to do it using the same method.. I imagine the code to do this would get really complicated and the end result would be ugly.

In my opinion, if you want to make a high quality animation you have better options. If you just wanted the animation with the year annotation, I would recommend first exporting the animation without the annotations, and then using something like [geemap.add_text_to_gif](https://geemap.org/timelapse/?h=add_text_to_gif#geemap.timelapse.add_text_to_gif) to add the annotations. Here's an example of how the annotations look (better quality than the previous one):

[image]

Again, you could use that function to add the legends as annotations (but you would still have to add the colored squares).

Another option that I would recommend is to use QGIS. You can use the [ee_plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ee_plugin/) to load your ee images as layers, create a layout with the legends, and export each frame separately. Then you can use those frames with e.g. [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/) to build the animation from the frames.

Comment: I will try this option! Thank you very much for your answer